# img не хочет растягиваться по высоте до родительского div (table-cell)

Tags: html, css

Вечер добрый! Пытаюсь решить задачку, кто хочет помочь?

Набросал тут
https://jsfiddle.net/qofnh97r/

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
.info {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.info1 {
    width: 70%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}
.info2 {
    width: 30%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
}
.info2 img {
   border: 1px #000 solid;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: text-top;
   width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info1">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="info2">
    <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть 2 `div`'а со стилем `display: table-cell`, красный и синий фон показывают, что высота у них одинаковая, т.е если я добавлю новые строки в `table` то высота синего блока увеличится.

Как заставить `img` растягиваться по высоте синего блока (соответственно зависит от таблицы)? Для `img` сделал `height: 100%` и `width: auto`, почему не работает? И заодно хотелось бы переместить `img` в правый угол в вверх:

[image: Хотелки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы высота была относительной, родителю нужно задать `Position:relative`, чтобы можно было свободно передвигать изображение, добавьте ему `Position:absolute` и спозиционируйте:

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.info1 {
  width: 70%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
}

.info2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
}

.info2 img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
        <td>Любой текст Любой текст</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="info2">
    <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот я лохундра! Спасибо, ваш код работает как часы!)